# How to find specific word in text file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file contains us,uss,ussr wanted to read specific word and length of word "uss" how can read using python

Comment: what's the content of the file? are the words comma(`,`) separated or whitespace separated?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
def findwords(text, length):
    return re.findall(r"\b\w{{{0}}}\b".format(length), text)
```

`\b` is a word boundary that ensures only entire words are matched.

`r"\w{{{0}}}".format(3)` results in `r"\w{3}"`. The double braces are necessary for escaping.

`\w` matches alphanumeric characters; if you want to avoid matching digits or the underscore with it, use `[^\W\d_]` in its place:

```
def findwords(text, length):
    return re.findall(r"\b[^\W\d_]{{{0}}}\b".format(length), text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regex ?

```
import re
help(re)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

For your trouble, you can use following regex :
 - `r'\w{3}'` : match 3 characters (no digit)

You can add `\s` before or after for match space or tabs.

Comment: I need to pass word length dynamically